# How to leave a `with` block without closing the resource?

Tags: python, with-statement

I am trying to achieve something similar to

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def open_head(file_path):
   with open(file_path, 'r') as f,
        TemporaryFile() as tf:
       for i in range(0,10):
           tf.write(f.read_line())
       return tf
```

such that the caller gets ownership of the temporary file.

In particular, I don't want the `with` statement to close the `TemporaryFile`. But if anything goes wrong before the `return`, I still want the `TemporaryFile` be closed by the `with` statement.

Ideally, I would then want to write the caller as

```
with open_head(file_path):
    # more code here
```

Is this possible somehow? E.g. by writing `return do_not_close(tf)` or some other utility functionality?

Or am I approaching this completely wrong and there is a more Pythonic way to return a `TemporaryFiles` or other resources, between functions while guaranteeing exception safety?

Comment: The whole point of the `with` statement is to close the file for you automatically.  If that's not what you want then don't use it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. `open_head` should take an already opened handle, which the *caller* is responsible for closing.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from itertools import islice


def head(file_path, fh):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in islice(f, 10):
            fh.write(line)


with TemporaryFile() as tf:
    head(file_path, tf)
    # Do other stuff with tf before it gets closed.
```

In general, anytime you are opening a file in an function, ask yourself if you can push the actual open up to the caller and accept a file-like object instead. Aside from making your code more reusable, it makes your code easier to test. `head` doesn't have to be called with an actual file: it can be called with any file-like object, such as `io.StringIO`.

---

Put another way: the `with` statement enforces the advice

> If you open the file, you are responsible for closing it as well.

The [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of that advice is

> If you aren't responsible for closing the file, you aren't responsible for opening the file, either.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `TemporaryFile` outside the context manager and wrap it in a `try except` block

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def open_head(path: str):
    try:
        tf = TemporaryFile()
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            for _ in range(10):
                tf.write(f.readline())
            return tf
    except Exception as e:
        tf.close()
        raise e
```

Comment: Might want a `raise` in that `except` block so we aren't discarding exceptions.

Comment: But now you've lost the guarantee that `tf` will every be properly closed. You opened it, but you don't know who, if anyone, will close it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but could you explicitly open the temporary file, return it from the function, and then close it when you want to?

```
def open_head(...):
   with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
      tf = TemporaryFile()
      for i in range(0,10):
         tf.write(f.read_line())
   return tf

tf = open_head(...)

# do some work

tf.close() # close the temporary file
```

Make sure you understand here though - by returning `tf` from the `open_head` function, you yourself are responsible for closing it properly.

The `with` keyword is used with context managers, which have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. The `__exit__` method is called when you leave the with block, which closes the file descriptor.

If you want to handle exceptions, you could yield the temporary file descriptor

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_head(...):
    tf = TemporaryFile()

    try:
        # do some work that might cause errors
        yield tf
    finally:
        os.close(tf)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am currently doing. The problem with this solution is, that if e.g. `f.read_line()` raises an exception, the `TemporaryFile` would be leaked. I am looking for an exception-safe way, preferably without using `try-catch`

Comment: @Vogelsgesang are you sure you need the try catch for this? The documentation for TemporaryFile (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) says "It will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit close when the object is garbage collected).". So if there is an exception then function execution is  interrupted, the local variable `tf` goes out of scope, garbage collected, and implicitly closed.

Comment: @Vogelsgesang see this example - https://gist.github.com/ychennay/319e14f35becb93b556e6637c7f5ce8b. The temporary file is closed as soon as it goes out of scope. When you return it from the `open_head` function though, you yourself are responsible for closing it.